# How can I use a persistent header component with ability to navigate in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to have a header that has buttons to go to different routes.

This is my App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Loading} exact />
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/history" component={History} />
                    <Route path="/trophies" component={Trophies} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}
```

Normally, I could just use `props.history.push('/history')` to navigate from within a component inside the `<Switch>`, however I want the `<Header />` to always show, with navigation...

How can I navigate from the header?

Header Code

```
import React from 'react';

import styled from 'styled-components';

export default function Header(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <HeaderWrap>
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
            <button onClick={() => props.history.push('/Home')}>Home</button>
        </HeaderWrap>
    );
}

const HeaderWrap = styled.div`
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    height: 15vh;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.useHistory` hook.
Or `<Link to="/">Home</Link>` component.

```
export default function Header(props) {
  const history = React.useHistory();
  return (
    <HeaderWrap>
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
        <button onClick={() => history.push('/Home')}>Home</button>
    </HeaderWrap>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you... Link was so obvious, not sure how I didn't think of it!

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap `BrowserRouter` or `Router` around the entire of `App` Component

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Loading} exact />
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
              <Route path="/history" component={History} />
              <Route path="/trophies" component={Trophies} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

you can also wrap it in `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I still receive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`
`> 10 |    <button onClick={() => props.history.push('/Home')}>Home</button>`

Comment: becuase you need to connect your component to react-router-dom. do it like this `export default withRouter(Header)` and also import it this way: `import { withRouter } from "react-router";`

Comment: This is good, however it needs to be `... from 'react-router-dom'`, But thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

#### App.js

```
             <Router>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Loading} exact />
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/history" component={History} />
                    <Route path="/trophies" component={Trophies} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

#### Header.js

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`

`export default withRouter(Header);`

Is the solution... thanks to @Mr.A for answer